# How to fit word length and height to fit container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit some text while designing on html and css, and I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I currently have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzaNR.png)

and the objective is to have [as it is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3692Z.png)

what seems the best way to do this?

```html
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="row h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 align-self-end">
                        <h1 class="text-uppercase text-white font-weight-bold adjust">Ignition<br>Dimension</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837192/how-to-fit-word-length-and-height-to-fit-container

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with just CSS. You need JavaScript to adjust the text size depending on its parent container. See https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

There is a proposal for CSS Container Queries but this has only been implemented in Chrome behind a flag

Except your parent container has the same width and height as your viewport. In that case, you could use `vh`/ `vw` to adjust the size based on the viewport